# openni_launch doesn't publish any data on the topics!

Tags: ros, kinect, openni-launch, publish

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I have installed ROS electric recently. I try to get point cloud from the Kinect sensor by the following command:

```
$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

It runs a few couple of nodelets and warns about the calibration .yaml files which seems to be OK. I can see a list of topics that it advertises, but neither "rviz" nor "rostopic hz" can capture any data from any topic starting with "/camera"!

However, with the following command:

```
$ roslaunch openni_camera openni_node.laucnh
```

I can capture point clouds streaming out from the Kinect sensor. Any idea why openni_launch doesn't publish any data on the topics?

Best,
Rasoul

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12176/openni_launch-doesn%27t-publish-any-data-on-the-topics!/) by [Rasoul](https://answers.ros.org/users/1477/rasoul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2011-11-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might have a look at [this answer by Patrick Mihelich](http://answers.ros.org/question/2993/registered-depth-only-works-sometimes-with#4768). Maybe compiling the latest version from svn helps for you too. Sometimes the openni.launch works if you restart it a lot. I were having similar problems and spent a lot time on continuous restarting until i got output from rostopic hz...

Finally i did a clean reinstall and switched to 64 bit Ubuntu which helped a lot (at least for me).

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2011-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [karthik](https://answers.ros.org/users/961/karthik/) on 2011-12-14**:
Hi, same issue here. Pointclouds are published and can see them when echoed topic wise. but not visible in rviz. can the reinstall b done using synaptic or should i remove n do it through svn?

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2011-12-01**:
Im glad that i could help you. Could you please accept my answer, so that its clear, that the problem is solved? Thanks a lot. :)

**Comment by [Rasoul](https://answers.ros.org/users/1477/rasoul/) on 2011-12-01**:
By compiling the latest version from svn, it started working properly. Thank you very much for your help!